# Faster way of foreign key reverse lookup django

Tags: django, foreign-keys

What is the faster way to do a reverse lookup of a foreign key entity in django?

Is it

```
 query_set = MyModel.objects.filter(ForeignModel=ForeignModelObject)
```

or

```
ForeignModelObject.mymodel_set.all()
```

When coming to a large set of records, which of the above is recommended?
Am using Mysql

Answer (score 0):

The second one is undoubtedly faster. But that's because they're not at all doing the same thing.

The first query means "give me all MyModels who are related to any ForeignModel with a parameter of 'something'."

The second means "given this ForeignModel instance, give me all MyModels that are related".

So they potentially give very different results, if there are more than one ForeignModel with that parameter. And as a result, the second query does not need to do a JOIN, so is a basic query on the MyModel table, whereas the first involves a JOIN between the models.

Comment: I actually meant both the queries to mean the same thing. Edited the question